# In Objective-C, How Would One Go About Limiting the Radius of the MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So basically, the scenario is described as thus:

For what I have right now, my application can zone in on the user's location with a blue dot showcasing itself on the iPhone. However, what I'm looking to do is have the application also zoom in onto the user's location close enough that they can see the streets, avenues, etc. that encircle them--but, at the same time, I want my application to "blur out" anything outside of a certain specified radius. So basically, for the latter part, you would be able to see every detail that is in, say, a 5-mile radius of your location clearly, but outside the radius, it would be blurred out.

I sincerely don't know if the latter portion of the above paragraph can be accomplished, but at the very least, can someone help me out on the zooming portion and, if it is possible, the blurring out portion as well? Thank you very much!

Comment: for zoom in to user current location, you need to set the region of map.